# How to always show the callouts in map view?

Tags: iphone

How can I always display map view callout? If we tab the map callout is hide once again tap the pin it showed. I don't want like this. I need always showing the callout never hide on any situation. In my map view only one pin and one callout. I am using below code for show the callout.

```
annotationView.canShowCallout  = YES;
```

Please help me. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this method if is there in code

```
- (void)deselectAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 0):

When an annotation is deselected, you get notified via

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

So in this method, you can reselect it, using

```
- (void)selectAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated
```